# NoSuchFileException uploading image into spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am wokring on spring boot, and i have created a folder `web` and `images` floders on this path : `myApp/src/web/images`

And when doing

```
private String saveFile(MultipartFile file, String fileName) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    String imagePath = new String(this.servletContext.getRealPath(this.imagesPath) + "/" + fileName);
    Path path = Paths.get(imagePath);
    Files.write(path, bytes);
    return imagePath;
}
```

i got this error :

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /private/var/folders/4g/wd_lgz8970sfh64zm38lwfhw0000gn/T/tomcat-docbase.8255351399752894174.8098/images/IMG_2018-01-06 15:18:48.486.jpg

where i should put the `images` folder in order to upload files into it successfully.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could save images into same `/myapp/src/web/image/` directory using a fairly straightforward way.

the path in your application start in `myapp` directory you just need to chain the folow path `/usr/web/images` and using a `FileOutputStream` object to save there.

An example below.

```
private String saveFile(MultipartFile file,String filename) throws IOException{
        final String imagePath = "src/web/images/"; //path
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(imagePath+filename);
        output.write(file.getBytes());

        return imagePath+filename;
}
```

> Second Edit

if you want to get a image via GET request you can make a method that accept a Request Parameter with the name of the image and produces IMAGE CONTENT TYPE. something like that. (this sample work with a different types of images.)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/show/",produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[]  showImage(@RequestParam("image") String image) throws IOException{
        final String imagePath = "src/web/images/";

        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(imagePath+image);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
    }
```

I'm using apache common dependency to get byte array

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, now i get the file under the `images` folder, do you know how can i access it via GET request?

Comment: you can create a method to return the bytes of a image with a given name, let me add a sample to the answer.

Comment: why is /user added to the path in /usr/web/images ?

Answer (score 1):

> i am working on spring boot, and i have created a folder web and
>   images folders on this path : myApp/src/web/images

and this exception :

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
>   /private/var/folders/4g/wd_lgz8970sfh64zm38lwfhw0000gn/T/tomcat-docbase.8255351399752894174.8098/images/IMG_2018-01-06
>   15:18:48.486.jpg

At runtime the `images` folder created in the application source code will not be physically located in an `images` folder of the folder that hosts the application as this path  : `myApp/src/web/images` is probably not considered by Spring Boot as the application is started.

In Spring Boot, you can access to static resources located in some specific folders such as `static` or `public`.
But I am not sure it will help you as you want to not only access to uploded files but also put content in the folder.

So I advise you to use another approach : put the images in a specific folder that is distinct of the application deployment folder.
Besides, generally, you want that the files be available after a shutdown/startup of the application.

So instead of using a relative path to the application to host the images :

```
myApp/src/web/images
```

use an absolute path (prefix with `/`) that is independently of the runtime folder of the application.