# Error while deploying Spring App (java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException)

Tags: spring, azure, intellij-idea, pom.xml

While deploying my app I got following error

```
Failed to update deployment(default) of Spring Cloud app(my-server), java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\server\target\server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

Im using IntelliJ and Azure Plugin (Deploy to Azure Spring Cloud option) following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/spring-cloud/quickstart?tabs=IntelliJ&pivots=programming-language-java

Comment: You can refer to [How to solve the java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076063/how-to-solve-the-java-nio-file-nosuchfileexception) and [NoSuchFileException uploading image into spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48127770/nosuchfileexception-uploading-image-into-spring-boot)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT the problem is that I dont even have server-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom file, I only have pom.xml files

Comment: Edit the question with more details regarding which tutorial you are following to deploy the Spring App to Azure and provide `pom.xml` file to check dependencies.

Comment: You can refer to [Introduction to Azure Spring Cloud with IntelliJ IDEA](https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/13/introduction-to-azure-spring-cloud-with-intellij-idea) and [Introduction to Azure Spring Cloud + IntelliJ IDEA](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/introduction-to-azure-spring-cloud-intellij-idea/ba-p/1372638)

Comment: Provide `pom.xml` file to check dependencies. Also check the location of `Maven:com.example:hellospring-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.` Refer to [Maven dependency jar version is different from pom.xml specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63540435/maven-dependency-jar-version-is-different-from-pom-xml-specification)

Comment: you want me to send you my pom.xml file? I didnt understand 'provide pom.xml' part

Comment: Yes, to debug the error, `pom.xml` can be helpful.

Comment: @DeepDave-MT here it is, my master pom https://pastebin.com/9SXTyb2g

also, after running command mvn compile the target folder is now generated, but there isnt 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom file in it